# Determine the number of columns in xml with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml data that I can't change.

```
<Root xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/">
  <Notes>
    <Note03>
      <Note03_Line01_Col00>3</Note03_Line01_Col00>
      <Note03_Line01_Col01>Contingent liabilities</Note03_Line01_Col01>
      <Note03_Line01_Col02/>
      <Note03_Line01_Col03/>
      <Note03_Line01_Col04/>
      <Note03_Line02_Col00/>
      <Note03_Line02_Col01>At the year end there are no contingent liabilities.</Note03_Line02_Col01>
      <Note03_Line02_Col02/>
      <Note03_Line02_Col03/>
      <Note03_Line02_Col04/>
      <Note03_Line03_Col00/>
      <Note03_Line03_Col01></Note03_Line03_Col01>
      <Note03_Line03_Col02/>
      <Note03_Line03_Col03/>
      <Note03_Line03_Col04/>
    </Note03>
  </Notes>
</Root>
```

My goal here is to determine the correct number of columns that this snippet has and apply an attribute set to it to reflect that number of columns.

I already have the attribute set, my problem is that I can't get my head around on how to determine the columns number. Is this achievable with xslt?

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use or can you use? Is `5` the number you are looking for?

Comment: I can use up to 3.0. The number that I'm looking for is 2, respectively: `Note03_Line01_Col00`, `Note03_Line01_Col01` on the 1st row.
`Note03_Line02_Col00`, `Note03_Line01_Col01` on the 2nd row - even though `Note03_Line02_Col00` doesn't have any data and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply compute the number `2` as the number of non-empty distinct children of the `Note03` element it suffices to use XPath:

```
count(distinct-values(Root/Notes/Note03/*[normalize-space()]/replace(local-name(), '^.*_Col', '')))
```

In most cases, assuming you want to transform that XML to something more table/row/cell like I am sure some XSLT 2/3 with `xsl:for-each-group` can consume and process that input XML.

Answer (score 0):

You say you can't change the XML, but you can - you are the proud owner of an XSLT processor.

With this kind of input, it's very often best to start by turning it into something more manageable, like

```
<Notes>
    <Note03>
      <Note03 line="1" col="0">3</Note03>
      <Note03 line="1" col="1">Contingent liabilities</Note03>
      <Note03 line="1" col="2"/>
      <Note03 line="1" col="3"/>
      ... etc ...
  </Notes>
```

I'm not sure how you define the "number of columns" that you want (max value of @col + 1 perhaps? or max number of distinct @col values for any line?), but either is now achieved using standard XSLT grouping techniques. Which means of course that it's dead easy in XSLT 2.0 but rather tricky in XSLT 1.0 -- and since you haven't told us which version you need, I'm not going to give you either in detail.